# How to reorder columns by the order of rows in the same matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, network-programming

Suppose I have a 10*10 matrix---A, in which the names and the order of columns are  identical to rows (a, b, c,.., j). Due to calculating the characteristics of the matrix, I have to reorder the rows and columns by their attribute, say "attr". Assuming that the attr of a, c, e equals to 1, attr of b, f, i, j equals to 2, and attr of d, g, h equals to 3. I figure out a way to reorder the rows as:

```
Anew <- rbind(subset(A, attr==1), subset(A, attr==2), subset(A, attr==3))
```

Now I have a new matrix `Anew`, in which the order of rows is a, c, e, b, f, i, j, d, g, h, and the order of columns remains the same as a,...,j. My question is that how I can reorder the column in `Anew` by the order of rows of `Anew`? I understand that I can use code such as

```
cbind(Anew[,a], Anew[,c],...,Anew[,h])
```

but is there a more efficient way to do this? If the matrix was 100*100, the code above is very insufficient. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `order` the `attr` and use that as row index

```
Anew <- A[order(as.numeric(attr(A, 'row.names'))),]
Anew
#          a          b           c           d           e          f          g           h            i          j
#a -0.545880758 -1.3169081 -0.07430856 -0.03373792  0.06735770  0.5266526  1.4520752  0.14379993 -0.571243248 -0.2327672
#c  0.419623149 -0.7622144 -1.70964518  0.61285136 -0.34365937  0.7696819 -0.4403340 -0.02557419 -1.673385810 -0.8133227
#e  0.847460017  0.3322444 -0.64859151  0.65738044 -0.25574457 -0.1961822  0.5713866 -0.07596102  0.361212489 -0.2148936
#b  0.536585304  0.5982691 -0.60515695 -0.58542756  0.01710596 -1.0736261  0.4082015 -0.88610999  0.422621775 -1.4203631
#f  0.266021979 -0.4690607 -0.09411013 -1.07418134 -0.46120796  0.2047497 -1.2799872 -1.35466363  1.056864213  0.1389452
#i -0.848370044  0.6099945 -0.11629639  0.16922669  0.33519430  1.0494212  1.3496121 -0.12316046  0.007165349  1.0451687
#j  0.002311942  0.5163357 -0.94382724 -1.82219032 -0.23186459  0.5609812 -1.5676166  0.00104102  0.101974336  1.2101739
#d -0.583627199 -1.4290903 -0.26869311  1.51712249 -0.66789220  1.7709054  1.3185662 -0.32773539 -1.136025931  0.4610693
#g  0.444585270 -0.3349868 -0.08554095 -4.46956441  1.47164158 -0.5965981 -1.2388796 -0.96080882 -1.992920453  0.8442304
#h -0.466495124  1.5362522  0.11953107  0.36904502 -0.09196032  1.1782477 -0.9225911  0.22495434  0.764385054 -1.3084503
```

If we want to do this for row and column

```
 Anew1 <- A[order(as.numeric(attr(A, 'row.names'))), order(as.numeric(attr(A, 'col.names')))]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
A <- matrix(rnorm(10*10), ncol=10, dimnames=list(letters[1:10], letters[1:10]))
attr(A, 'row.names') <-  as.character(c(1, 2, 1,3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2))
attr(A, 'col.names') <-  as.character(c(1, 2, 1,3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2))
```

Comment: Thank you. It works well. One more question, it seems like if I don't set the row names and the column names as character, this process won't work. Do you mind yo explain why? Thanks again.

Comment: @akrum, I appreciate your help. More precisely, if I name the rows and columns only by
`rownames(A) <- letters[1:10]`

`colnames(A)<-rownames(A)`

The whole process will not give the same results and I am wondering why.

Comment: @tzu I tried that and still got the same result.  Look at the `attr`.  Do you have that in your dataset?

Comment: Oops, sorry. I was wrong. My problem is actually "if I don't reorder the rows and columns at the same time, it won't have the same results provided above." To be clearer, if I do

`Anew <- A[order(as.numeric(attr(A, 'row.names'))),]`

first, and then further do

`Anew <- A[,order(as.numeric(attr(A, 'col.names')))]`

I will have weird result which just contains the name of the columns, rather the result from the code

`Anew1 <- A[order(as.numeric(attr(A, 'row.names'))), order(as.numeric(attr(A, 'col.names')))]`

Could you explain why? Thank you!

Comment: @tzu I showed you two options , i.e. 1) just ordering by rows, 2) ordering both rows and columns.  The reason is that you are ordering on the initial dataset.  In the second step, you need to order on the newly created 'Anew' i.e. `Anew[,order(as.numeric(attr(Anew, 'col.names'..`

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I get why. Your explanation is fantastic. Just one reminder that your code

`Anew[,order(as.numeric(attr(Anew, 'col.names')))]`

in fact should be

`Anew[,order(as.numeric(attr(A, 'col.names')))]`

due to the attributes are not passed from A to Anew.